# Android Studio installation error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am trying to install Android Studio on lubuntu, but I get the following error:

```
Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.createClassPath(UrlClassLoader.java:179)
   at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.<init>(UrlClassLoader.java:173)
   at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader$Builder.get(UrlClassLoader.java:128)
   at com.intellij.ide.BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.initClassLoader(BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.java:68)
   at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:32)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Resource not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./../lib/bootstrap.jar,file:./../lib/extensions.jar,file:./../lib/util.jar,file:./../lib/jdom.jar,file:./../lib/log4j.jar,file:./../lib/trove4j.jar,file:./../lib/jna.jar], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.14)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   ...6 more
```

Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.getUnsafe(ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.java:2787)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.<clinit>(ConcurrentIntObjectHashMap.java:2752)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentIntObjectMap(ContainerUtil.java:2334)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentRefValueIntObjectHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentRefValueIntObjectHashMap.java:31)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentWeakValueIntObjectHashMap.<init>(ConcurrentWeakValueIntObjectHashMap.java:31)
   at com.intellij.util.containers.ContainerUtil.createConcurrentIntObjectWeakValueMap(ContainerUtil.java:2362)
   at com.intellij.openapi.util.Key.<clinit>(Key.java:38)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:202)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:251)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:234)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:224)
   at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find 'theUnsafe' field in the class sun.misc.Unsafe
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.getUnsafe(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:44)
   at com.intellij.util.concurrency.AtomicFieldUpdater.<clinit>(AtomicFieldUpdater.java:38)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.14)
   ...15 more
```

I am using lubuntu, based on ubuntu 15.10. I have updated all the software,  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have JDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project and select -> Compile Module, and then re-start the project and it should work again.